# How to avoid merging media queries declaring variables withing Angular CSS minifier?

Tags: css, angular

I am declaring variables withing media queries in CSS, but when Angular CSS minifier is merging the declarations together, breaking the style.

Is there a way to configure this behavior?

My CSS is

```
:root { --grid-max: 94%; }

@media (min-width: 400px) { :root { --grid-max: var(--grid-4); } }

@media (min-width: 500px) { :root { --grid-max: var(--grid-5); } }

@media (min-width: 600px) { :root { --grid-max: var(--grid-6); } }

@media (min-width: 700px) { :root { --grid-max: var(--grid-7); } }

@media (min-width: 800px) { :root { --grid-max: var(--grid-8); } }

@media (min-width: 1200px) { :root { --grid-max: var(--grid-12); } }
```

The minified version is the following:

```
:root {
 --grid-3:273px;
 --grid-4:370px;
 --grid-5:468px;
 --grid-6:565px;
 --grid-7:663px;
 --grid-8:760px;
 --grid-12:1150px;
 --grid-max:94%;
}
```

The minifier computed the values of the variables (that is not the issue), but it also merged all media queries into a single statement, changing the behavior of the original CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**This doesn't actually solve the problem**, but it is the workaround I have adopted for now.

Within angular.json it is possible to configure it not to do optimization regarding styles while still optimizing the js. In projects.architect.build.configurations.production.optimization, simply set styles to false and scripts to true.

```
          "optimization": {"scripts":  true, "styles":  false},
```